# Wii browser capabilities: Specifically: chat/JS/Flash/local storage

Tags: nintendo-wii

I've been asked about the specific capabilities of the Nintendo Wii.

- Does it have a web browser? If so, is it suitably enabled with JavaScript/Flash, etc.? I'm thinking could it support a chatroom-type scenario?
- Is it possible for the web browser to save web content onto some form of local storage? I'm thinking chat logs, web pages and/or images/videos.

I don't personally have a Wii and don't know anyone that has who can give me a definitive answer. Hopefully one of you guys will have tried pushing a Wii browser further than most!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Wii browser is called the [Internet Channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Channel).  It has limited support for JS and Flash, but I believe it provides some form of local storage.

Comment: In addition, it's Opera-based, in case that information is relevant.

Comment: Thanks guys :) Seems enough to answer the questions I was posed.

Answer (score 3):

The Internet Channel on the Wii is a special build of Opera (9.2, I believe...?) with support for Flash 7 and JS. If you're looking for a great breakdown, check out **[this Opera article on Wii browser support](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/opera9/?platform=wii)**. Sadly, to my knowledge, the browser doesn't support localStorage - the best you get is Cookies. However, my testing could be off, so I encourage you to check on your own.

If you're looking for a nicer way to interact with the 4 Wii remotes on a given page, I wrote **[a library](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/wii-js)** that wraps it all up into a nice convenient (and sane) interface. It includes tools to help debug things in the browser as well, which might come in handy for your testing.